# Slow search by index query LIKE% MYSQL

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, sql-like

i have table with 100 000 000 rows so large.
Structure of table

```
id         int          INDEX(not primary not unique just index)
lang_index varchar(5)   INDEX
name       varchar(255) INDEX
enam       varchar(255) INDEX
```

Ok. i do query

1 Query

```
"SELECT name FROM table WHERE lang_index='en' AND name LIKE 'myname%'"
```

Speed is ok for this large table. around 0.02 sec.

i try 
2 Query

```
"SELECT name FROM table WHERE lang_index='en' AND (name LIKE 'myname%' OR enam LIKE 'myname%')"
```

Very very slow around 230 sec!!!

then i try this 
3 Query

```
"SELECT name FROM table WHERE lang_index='en' AND enam LIKE 'myname%'"
```

Speed is fantastic. around 0.02 sec.

Then i explode my 2nd query for two queries (1 and 3 query) its faster. around 0.04 sec but it not simply.

Why my query is slow? Two queries much faster than one. 
I need do this `"SELECT name FROM table WHERE lang_index='en' AND (name LIKE 'myname%' OR enam LIKE 'myname%')"`
How i can make it faster?

Comment: What does EXPLAIN your_query says?

Comment: EXPLAIN said...
id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra
1 SIMPLE lal ref lang_index,name,eman lang_index 18 const 2048048 Using where

Answer (score 5):

The `OR` keyword drives MySQL's optimizer crazy.

You might try something like this.

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE lang_index='en' AND name LIKE 'myname%'
UNION
SELECT name FROM table WHERE lang_index='en' AND enam LIKE 'myname%'
```

Or you might consider FULLTEXT searching. It requires MyISAM or a version of MySQL 5.6 or later.

**EDIT***
It's hard to know exactly what's going on with these optimization things.  Can you try this? This will see whether the language selection is fouling you up.

```
 SELECT name 
   FROM table 
  WHERE (name LIKE 'myname%' OR enam LIKE 'myname%')
```

Can you try this?

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE lang_index='en' AND name LIKE 'myname%'
UNION ALL
SELECT name FROM table WHERE lang_index='en' AND enam LIKE 'myname%'
```

It won't give a perfect result -- it will have duplicate name items -- but it will skip a `DISTINCT` deduplicating step in your query.

You might also try this.

```
SELECT name 
  FROM table
 WHERE lang_index='en'
   AND id IN (
    SELECT id from table 
     WHERE (name LIKE 'myname%' OR enam LIKE 'myname%'))
```

Comment: Thanks, but i try and test each your query. All it slow. I stopped on version with two queries. I can't understand logic of mysql i try see EXPLAIN info for each one query all ok mysql use index but it slow. Faster result - use two queries. Thanks for try help me guys. Thanks again.